# How to show matched column only in table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Tried to show matched column only in the table but I do not know how to do it. If anyone knows pls help to find the solutions.

app.component.ts:

```
 columnsOnly = ['name', 'id', 'rank']; 
  items = [
    { name: 'jean', surname: 'kruger', id: 1, place: 'ckh', rank: null },
    { name: 'bobby2', surname: 'marais2', id: 2, place: 'ckh', rank: null },
    { name: 'jean3', surname: 'kruger3', id: 3, place: 'ckh', rank: null },
    { name: 'bobby4', surname: 'marais4', id: 4, place: 'ckh', rank: null },
    { name: 'jean5', surname: 'kruger5', id: 5, place: 'ckh', rank: null },
    { name: 'bobby6', surname: 'marais6', id: 6, place: 'ckh', rank: null }
  ];
```

app.component.html:

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of items[0] | keys: index as i">

        <span *ngIf="head == columnsOnly[i]">
        {{head}} </span>

      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
      <td *ngFor="let list of item | keys">{{item[list]}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-71f59e?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you not iterate over columnsOnly ?

```
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let column of columnsOnly">
    <span>{{column}} </span>
  </th>
</tr>

<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
  <td *ngFor="let column of columnsOnly">{{item[column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Update**, Well, in general it's better than our array of columns was an array of object with two properties, e.g. "label" and "field". So, imagine you has an array columns like

```
  columnsOnly = [
    {label:'First Name',field:'firstName'},
    {label:'Sur Name',field:'surname'}, 
    {label:'ID Type',field:'idType'},
    {label:'Near Place',field:'nearPlace'}
  ];
```

We change the loop as

```
  <th *ngFor="let column of columnsOnly">
    <!--see that you use column.label-->
    <span>{{column.label}} </span>
  </th>

  <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <!--see that you use column.field-->
     <td *ngFor="let column of columnsOnly">{{item[column.field]}}</td>
  </tr>
```

**Update 2** another aproach is to have defined all columns and make a "map"

```
columns=['First Name','ID Type']
columnsOnly=this.columns
                 .map(x=>this.columnsAll.find(c=>c.label==x))
```

(columnsAll we has defined the "label" and "field"

Comment: Sometimes getting blank value -{{item[column]}}

Comment: if column has as value a name of the property of the object and has value, should be work. In your e.g. "rank" is null, so no show any value-. Be careful, Angular is case-sensitive -it's not the same "Rank" than "rank"-

Comment: Please check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qja73a?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: In this condition how we can match it? Suppose array property name camelcase?   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksymng?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I updated the answer. The idea is that columns was an array of object with two properties: `label` -the label you see in the header of the table, and `field` the real name of the column. Well, you can also to has an array of strings and imagine a way to parse the array to get the title or the name of the columns, but really I think that is more "robust" using the approach of an array of object

Comment: Can u match column names and array key names?

Comment: Check this QA: 67470839

Comment: @Sansara, you always can "map" the array of strings like the another updated I just made